# deobfuscator for .Net

Tags: .net, obfuscation

Do you know any good deobfuscator for .Net?

Comment: I didn't know such things existed for other languages.

Comment: Google didn't help? There were several on the front page for *deobfuscator .net*.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - I also don't know.. There is some for .Net but not so good.

Comment: @John at CashCommons - In fact I found some(dedot) but they were not helpful. If you know of please help

Answer (score 29):

The most powerful .NET deobfuscator I know is [de4dot - Deobfuscator for .NET](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot). It is open source, actively developed, and it claims to support the following obfuscators:

- Babel.NET
- CliSecure
- CodeVeil
- Crypto Obfuscator
- DeepSea
- Dotfuscator
- .NET Reactor
- Eazfuscator.NET
- Goliath.NET
- MaxtoCode
- Skater.NET
- SmartAssembly
- Spices.NET
- Xenocode

I have tested it myself with several obfuscators, and de4dot has deobfuscated the assemblies without problems.

Answer (score 3):

As Smi answered de4dot is the most powerful.

It has a plugin for [Telerik JustDecompiler](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) (free .NET decompiler) and it is very handy plug in.

When you install it

- Go to **Plugins**
- Then **Plugin Manager**
- In **Available Plugins** you will see **De4Dot Deobfuscator**
- Then **Download**